# How is the Theta angle of $SU(5)$ grand unified theory related to the three Theta angles in the $U(1) \times SU(2) \times SU(3)$ standard model?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, yang-mills, beyond-the-standard-model, instantons

There are three Theta angles in the $U(1) \times SU(2) \times SU(3)$ standard model:

call them
$$U(1): \theta' F \tilde{F}$$
$$SU(2):\theta'' F \tilde{F}$$
$$SU(3):\theta''' F \tilde{F}$$

But there is a single Theta angle of $SU(5)$ grand unified theory
$$SU(5):\Theta  F \tilde{F}$$

### Question

How is the single Theta angle of $SU(5)$ grand unified theory related to the three Theta angles in the $U(1) \times SU(2) \times SU(3)$ standard model? How can the three parameters $\theta',\theta'',\theta'''$ be related to a single $\Theta$ of $SU(5)$?

Comment: Isn't it just a matter of expanding the $F_5\tilde F_5 = F_3\tilde F_3 + F_2\tilde F_2+ F_1\tilde F_1$ etc. ?

Comment: But on one side there is only a Theta, on the other sides have three. But we do not seem to say the SU(5) GUT only gives a Theta in SM